# How to compile RealSense examples?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, cmake, realsense

I have cloned the RealSense official source code from their [Github page](https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/). There was a problem when I was compiling the example *align-advanced*. The following is my terminal situation:

```
$ cd ~/librealsense/examples/align-advanced
$ mkdir build
$ cd build
~/librealsense/examples/align-advanced/build$ cmake ..
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 7.5.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 7.5.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/automation/librealsense/examples/align-advanced/build
~/librealsense/examples/align-advanced/build$ make
~/librealsense/examples/align-advanced/build$
```

As you can see, nothing happens after typing `make`, and no executable files appear in the *build* folder.
The contents of offical CMakeList.txt are as follows:

```
# License: Apache 2.0. See LICENSE file in root directory.
# Copyright(c) 2019 Intel Corporation. All Rights Reserved.
#  minimum required cmake version: 3.1.0
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1.0)

project(RealsenseExamplesAlignAdvanced)

if(BUILD_GRAPHICAL_EXAMPLES)
    add_executable(rs-align-advanced rs-align-advanced.cpp ../../third-party/imgui/imgui.cpp ../../third-party/imgui/imgui_draw.cpp ../../third-party/imgui/imgui_impl_glfw.cpp)
    set_property(TARGET rs-align-advanced PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 11)
    target_link_libraries(rs-align-advanced ${DEPENDENCIES})
    include_directories(rs-align-advanced ../../common ../../third-party/imgui)
    set_target_properties (rs-align-advanced PROPERTIES FOLDER Examples)
    install(TARGETS rs-align-advanced RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR})
endif()
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

CMake was intended to be run from the **top-level** directory of the entire project. This is a general CMake rule-of-thumb; it *typically* applies to **any** CMake-based project, not only RealSense.

If you want to enable the compilation of the RealSense examples, you can control it via CMake with the `BUILD_EXAMPLES` variable, as seen the [Build Configuration](https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/wiki/Build-Configuration) documentation. This only builds a small subset of the examples, however. To build the `align-advanced` examples, you also need to set `BUILD_GRAPHICAL_EXAMPLES`:

```
cd ~/librealsense
mkdir build; cd build
cmake -DBUILD_EXAMPLES=true -DBUILD_GRAPHICAL_EXAMPLES=true ..
make
```

Comment: Hello squareskittles,
    Thanks for your answering！
    I followed your instructions. However, after typing in `make`, terminal still does not prompt, and no executable file appears in the build folder.
    The official _CMakeLists.txt_ file of the program is added to the question.

Comment: @simon00715 You will also need the `BUILD_GRAPHICAL_EXAMPLES` variable set to build the `align-advanced` example. Without it, only a couple examples will build. I encourage you to check out the linked RealSense Build configuration page to see all of the CMake variables you can set to affect the build. Also, be sure to remove the CMake build folders you used in previous configurations to ensure the old cached data is not still affecting your new build attempts.